# Can I go to the Schengen area for only one day and then to Turkey the next day?

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, filipino-citizens

I am Filipino citizen and I have a National Visa (Type D) valid but I want to go to Istanbul, Turkey first with an e-Visa. Philippine Passport holders can visit Turkey for 30 days with an e-Visa as long as they have an active Schengen visa/Residence permit.

The problem is, I have a scholarship and I need to show proof (plane tickets) that I departed from my home country and landed in the Schengen area. I might get into trouble with my scholarship if they see that I went to Turkey first - it's too complicated to explain this to them because I'm basically just going to be a tourist there.

My other reason of going to Amsterdam first and then flying to Turkey is because it is cheaper. It will only cost me $700 and if I go straight to Istanbul and then to Amsterdam it'll be almost $900.

Is there some kind of a rule/minimum days of stay in the Schengen area for an individual before he/she can leave the Schengen, whatsoever?

I have a multiple entry visa. I just don't want to get into trouble for only spending one day in the EU and then going to Turkey for two weeks and then coming back again.

Will that be somewhat problematic?

Comment: I can go back again after 2 weeks of being in Turkey, right?

Comment: One remark on your visa says that you have to register your presence with the immigration authorities at your place of residence *immediately* after entry. Similar remarks are quite common on German D visas and is just a reminder that you have to register with the immigration authorities after having moved to Germany. I have however never seen the specification 'immediately' used like this and would not be sure if you violate the requirement if you enter the Schengen area, go to Turkey for two weeks and not until then go to your place of residence to register.

Comment: Oh wow. Thank you very much for informing me about that. The German embassy did not even point that out to me and I don't speak German! I think it's primarily because I am an exchange student and a friend said it takes a long time to schedule an appointment for a residence permit so I must go there immediately. 

May I ask, is there anything written in the visa talking about me entering the Schengen area through Germany alone? And if can't visit other Schengen countries? @Tor-EinarJarnbjo. Thank you very much!

Comment: My accommodation will not be in the Netherlands. My University is near the Netherlands border and Schipol is the cheapest and nearest airport to fly to, so I am landing in Amsterdam. @pnuts

Comment: If you're only allowed to visit particular SCHENGEN countries, it is annotated on the visa. Those are Limited Territorial Visas, and unusual.  http://www.schengenvisainfo.com/schengen-visa-types/

Comment: Is it annotated in mine? @PaultheSheik

Comment: I don't see any notations restricting your travel within the SCHENGEN ares. I am looking at my own visas and it's the same except the notes on the second picture. Get a German speaker to read those notes to you however I believe you're fine

Comment: @PaultheSheik The OP has a type D visa for Germany. An LTV visa is a special form of the type C (short-term) visa and completely irrelevant for this question.

Comment: @Tor-Einar Jarnbjo Did you understand what I wrote to him? Did you follow the conversation? You might need a lesson in English comprehension.

Comment: @PaultheSheik I follow the conversation and understand you perfectly well. The OP has a German type D visa and asked (additionally in a comment) if he can visit other Schengen countries. You answered that he can do it, unless he has an LTV visa. The problem is, that there is no such thing as a type D visa with limited territorial validity. A type D visa *always* gives you the right to travel to other Schengen states (max 90 days in a 180 days period).

Comment: @Tor-Einar Jarnbjo Stop splitting hairs with unnecessary criticism. Does he have an LTV Visa? Is the information I gave him wrong? No! I even provided the link so he could educate himself further on SCHENGEN visa types. Clearly he has learned some things from me. I see no need to continue this discourse further.

Comment: @SheikPaul please do not engage in ad hominem attacks.

Comment: If you just want to visit Istanbul, you might want to find a flight with a long layover there (i.e. you have one booking)

Comment: I'm gonna be traveling there with a friend for two weeks. @Vince

Answer (score 1):

> Is there some kind of a rule/minimum days of stay in the Schengen area
>   for an individual before he/she can leave the Schengen, whatsoever?

**No**, of course not. Plenty of people enter the Schengen area for a few hours, for example during a long layover. However be aware that you will have an exit stamp next to your entry stamp, so it would be easy to infer you immediately left if someone takes a look at your passport.

> Will that be somewhat problematic?

Neither the Schengen border guards nor the visa issuing agencies in the respective countries care about your visits, as long as they're within the duration of the visa. However we have no way of knowing if you'll get in trouble with whoever issued you the scholarship.